# How to read the stack segment of a C program?

Tags: c, linux

I am developing a Hobby operating system, for that I want to know the mechanism of memory allocation in Linux, to understand that, I created a simple C program that defines a `unsigned char` of some hex numbers and then runs in a empty infinite loop, I did this to keep the process alive. Then I used `pmap` to get page-mapping information. Now I know the location of stack segment, also I have created a program that uses  `process_vm_readv` syscall to read the contents of that address, all I see a stream of `00` when I read the contents of stack segment and some random numbers at last, How can I be able to figure out how the array is stored in the stack segment?

If that is possible, how can I analyze the hex stream to extract meaningful information ?

Comment: Use a pointer? Try writing and reading from it and see if the contents of the stack change.

Comment: When you say "hobby operating system", do you mean an operating system built on top of the Linux kernel? Or do you make your own kernel? If you want a reference implementation to read and understand you really should go back to the *very* early Linux kernels (from the first couple of years) as the modern are *very* advanced. Or better yet get a couple of good books and some kernels *designed* to be used for tutoring. I also recommend [the OSDev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) as a resource to find information.

Comment: Did you ensure that there is some useful information on the stack? If you only define a variable and don't do anything with it, the compiler might remove it from the program. You will never find that value on your stack then. Even if you print the variable the compiler might optiimize and keep in a register

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, The OS is being built from scratch, till now I have built basic I/O , heap and a display driver. I am now starting with user-space , so wanted to dig in some practices used by Linux.

Comment: @Gerhardh A way to force it into the stack is to take its address.

Comment: @Gerhardh , Yes, now I displayed the base address of the array, and compared it with what `pmap` showed, from that I am sure that the array is in stack segment as its base address is in the range of stack segment starting address.

Comment: I am assuming you have stack segment starting address. You should also need to know the stack frame structure in-order to read the auto variable (unsigned char) content.

Comment: @AjithCNarayanan , Yes, I do have starting address

Comment: @NarasimhaPrasannaHN You might want to declare your char array as volatile. If not, it may get optimized out because the compiler detects that you don't do anything with the data inside your array.

Comment: @NarasimhaPrasannaHN It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. The OS only 'allocates' the stack for your program. Decisions like where in the stack the individual variables are placed or how the stack itself is organized is upto the program itself. These decisions are made, in your case, by your compiler. The OS just allocates a chunk of memory for you and lets your program run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I am adding a demonstration for accessing address space of a remote process, There are two programs local.c which will read and write a variable in another program named remote.c (These program assumes `sizeof(int)==4` )

local.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[4];
    struct iovec local[1];
    struct iovec remote[1];
    int pid;
    void *addr;

    printf("Enter remote pid\n");
    scanf("%d",&pid);

    printf("Enter remote address\n");
    scanf("%p", &addr);

    local[0].iov_base = buf;
    local[0].iov_len = 4;

    remote[0].iov_base = addr;
    remote[0].iov_len = 4;



    if(syscall(SYS_process_vm_readv,pid,local,1,remote,1,0) == -1) {
    perror("");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("read : %d\n",*(int*)buf);

    *(int*)buf = 4321;

    if(syscall(SYS_process_vm_writev,pid,local,1,remote,1,0) == -1) {
    perror("");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

remote.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int main()
{

    int a = 1234;

    printf("%d  %p\n",getpid(),&a);
    while(a == 1234);

    printf ("'a' changed to %d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

And if you run this on a Linux machine,

```
[ajith@localhost Desktop]$ gcc remote.c -o remote -Wall
[ajith@localhost Desktop]$ ./remote
4574  0x7fffc4f4eb6c
'a' changed to 4321
[ajith@localhost Desktop]$


[ajith@localhost Desktop]$ gcc local.c -o local -Wall
[ajith@localhost Desktop]$ ./local
Enter remote pid
4574
Enter remote address
0x7fffc4f4eb6c
read : 1234
[ajith@localhost Desktop]$
```

Using the similar way you can read stack frame to the io-vectors, But you need to know the stack frame structure format to parse the values of local variables from stack frame. stack frame contains function parameters, return address, local variables, etc

Comment: why use syscall instead of calling `process_vm_readv` directly?

Comment: some Linux distributions doesn't expose `process_vm_readv()` system call @ChrisDodd